# Multiple INNER JOINS in VBA from ACCESS database

Tags: excel, vba

I used Access query designer to set up the joins but it didn't work in VBA.
I get Syntax Error in FROM '-2147217900 (80040e14)'

```
Set Signal = cnn.Execute("SELECT Table2.W, Table5.Attribute " _
    & " FROM (((((Table7 " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table5 )" _
    & " INNER JOIN Table6) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table1) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table2 " _
    & " ON Table1.DB_ID = Table2.Attrib_Def) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table4 " _
    & " ON Table2.Opt_Obj_ID = Table4.Signal " _
    & " AND Table2.Object_ID = Table4.Node " _
    & " ON Table6.DB_ID = Table4.Signal) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table3 " _
    & " ON Table4.Node = Table3.Node " _
    & " ON Table5.DB_ID = Table3.Node" _
    & " ON Table7.DB_ID = Table3.Message " _
    & " WHERE (((Table1.Name)='TypeA') " _
    & " AND ((Table7.Name)='XX') " _
    & " AND ((Table6.Name)='X')) ")
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL created by Access query designer? Usually it goes `INNER JOIN .. ON ... INNER JOIN ... ON...` but you have to `ONs` next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet to troubleshoot things like this is to send the string that is generated to your debug/immediate window:

```
Sub test()
    Sql = "SELECT Table2.W, Table5.Attribute " _
    & " FROM (((((Table7 " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table5 )" _
    & " INNER JOIN Table6) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table1) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table2 " _
    & " ON Table1.DB_ID = Table2.Attrib_Def) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table4 " _
    & " ON Table2.Opt_Obj_ID = Table4.Signal " _
    & " AND Table2.Object_ID = Table4.Node " _
    & " ON Table6.DB_ID = Table4.Signal) " _
    & " INNER JOIN Table3 " _
    & " ON Table4.Node = Table3.Node " _
    & " ON Table5.DB_ID = Table3.Node" _
    & " ON Table7.DB_ID = Table3.Message " _
    & " WHERE (((Table1.Name)='TypeA') " _
    & " AND ((Table7.Name)='XX') " _
    & " AND ((Table6.Name)='X')) "

    Debug.Print Sql
End Sub
```

Copy out the sql produced when you run this and head over to a text editor so you can properly indent this mess:

```
SELECT Table2.W, Table5.Attribute  
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        Table7  INNER JOIN Table5 
                    ) 
                    INNER JOIN Table6
                )  
                INNER JOIN Table1
            )  
            INNER JOIN Table2  
            ON Table1.DB_ID = Table2.Attrib_Def
        )  
        INNER JOIN Table4  
        ON Table2.Opt_Obj_ID = Table4.Signal  
            AND Table2.Object_ID = Table4.Node  
        ON Table6.DB_ID = Table4.Signal
    )  
    INNER JOIN Table3  
    ON Table4.Node = Table3.Node  
    ON Table5.DB_ID = Table3.Node 
    ON Table7.DB_ID = Table3.Message  
WHERE 
    (
        (
            (
                Table1.Name
            ) ='TypeA'
        )  
        AND 
        (
            (
                Table7.Name
            )='XX'
        )  
        AND 
        (
            (
                Table6.Name
            )='X'
        )
    )
```

The thing with Access's GUI for producing SQL is that it gets stupid about the parentheses. In this case, not a single parentheses is needed. I don't see anything super off here, but its ugly and difficult to diagnose what's happening. Instead use:

```
SELECT Table2.W, Table5.Attribute  
FROM Table7  
    INNER JOIN Table3
        ON Table3.Message = Table3.DB_ID  
    INNER JOIN Table5
        ON Table5.DB_ID = Table3.Node
    INNER JOIN Table4
        ON Table4.Node = Table3.Node 
    INNER JOIN Table6 
        ON Table6.DB_ID = Table4.Signal
    INNER JOIN Table2
        ON Table2.Opt_Obj_ID = Table4.Signal  
    INNER JOIN Table1
        ON Table1.DB_ID = Table2.Attrib_Def
WHERE
    Table1.Name ='TypeA' AND
    Table7.Name = 'XX' AND
    Table6.Name = 'X';
```

This is much cleaner and easier to follow. The reason we were able to remove all those parantheses is because it's only `INNER JOIN` and the `WHERE` statement is all 'ANDs'. If there were some `OR` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` hanging out in there then we'd have to be more judicial, but I can guarantee you that Access will stick way way way way too many parentheses in there. It just loves em.

Anyway putting this back into VBA you can use:

```
Sub test()
    ...all your existing code...

    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT Table2.W, Table5.Attribute"
    sql = sql & " FROM Table7"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table3"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table3.Message = Table3.DB_ID"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table5"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table5.DB_ID = Table3.Node"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table4"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table4.Node = Table3.Node"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table6"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table6.DB_ID = Table4.Signal"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table2"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table2.Opt_Obj_ID = Table4.Signal"
    sql = sql & " INNER JOIN Table1"
    sql = sql & "     ON Table1.DB_ID = Table2.Attrib_Def"
    sql = sql & " WHERE"
    sql = sql & " Table1.Name ='TypeA' AND"
    sql = sql & " Table7.Name = 'XX' AND"
    sql = sql & " Table6.Name = 'X';"

    Set Signal = cnn.Execute(sql)
End Sub
```

In the end, there is no guarantee that removing the parentheticals will help, but it will definitely remove some of the ambiguity and help you diagnose why it's not executing properly.